# How to save object in FastAPI which have related model in it?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have simple model instances which have M2M relation: `Doctor` and `Branch`:

```
doctor_branch_association = Table(
    "doctor_branch",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("doctor_id", Integer, ForeignKey("doctor.id")),
    Column("branch_id", Integer, ForeignKey("branch.id")),
)


class Doctor(TimestampedModel, Base):
    ...

    branches = relationship("Branch", secondary=doctor_branch_association, back_populates="doctors")


class Branch(TimestampedModel, Base):
    ...
    doctors = relationship("Doctor", secondary=doctor_branch_association, back_populates="branches")
```

I want to create **POST** `/doctors` method, to allow create doctors within branches. So I create a Pydantic model for that:

```
class BaseDoctor(BaseModel):
    ...
    branches: List[int]
```

Then in my crud method I trying to create that instance by passing pydantic object to SQLAlchemy model like this:

```
db_obj = self.model(**obj_in.model_dump())
```

And I realised, that SQLALchemy waiting for `Branch` instances instead of ids. The question is, what is the best way to solve that problem? I can rewrite my crud method and replace `branches` ids with `Branch` instances which I will found by id, but I am not sure that this is the best way, maybe there are any other best practice to achieve this?